# In Java how can I use html tags on System.out.println()

Tags: java, html, tags, output, string-formatting

In Java how can I show my System.out.println() outputs with HTML tag outputs  like italic(`<i>`), bold(`<b>`) or paragraph(`<p>`). I only want to  organize my outputs like **`here is the your output`** or *`here is the another output`*

Comment: You want html tags like formatting on you console?

Comment: Where `out` is directed to?

Comment: yes . Exactly thats I want it. I want to formatting my console outputs with html tags.

Comment: You can't have HTML tags outputted to a console. You can have bold or italic font outputted... Depending on what console you are outputting to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can do that!You will have to embed necessary formatting:
For eg: In order to get your output to be bold, you need to do the following:

**System.out.println((char)27 +"[1m testing bold");**

The (char) 27 is an escape sequence, the [ is followed by a set of ; separated values for different formatting types (see below), followed by an m. You will need to play around with this.

Some attributes:

0 Normal (clear all)
1 bold
2 dim
4 underline
5 blink
7 reverse
8 blank
9 overstrike
22 normal intensity (cancel bold and blank)
24 underline off
25 blink off
27 reverse off
28 blank off
29 overstrike off
30 black
31 red
32 green
33 yellow
34 blue
35 magenta
36 cyan
37 white
40 black background
41 red background
42 green background

Comment: This doesn't work everywhere, for instance console in Win 7 doesn't interpret it this way, it just prints `←[1m testing bold`

Comment: such things worked in MS DOS, and as I recall it was necessary to run additional driver. otherwise these symbols were printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can't change format of the font in text terminal.
This is possible and easy in graphic applications, made in Java and managed by Java API

Comment: thanks about answer. Actually I  explore I can use that with  Swing or AWT but I wondered can I use on text terminal. And I learned I cant use it thanks to you.

Comment: @enginear You are welcome . Check this link for font changes in AWT http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/FontBOLD.htm

Comment: @enginear you can't do it with default OS settings, but you can change them with something like [jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/). You wouldn't be able to use HTML though, but format described in [Anmol's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24722464/1393766)